# The affine cone of a projective variety is contractible?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology

Let's work over $\mathbb{C}$.

It seems to me that if $V\subset \mathbb{P}^{n-1}$ is a projective complex variety then the affine cone $C(V)\subset \mathbb{C}^n$ should be contractible. Here $C(V)$ has the subspace topology. Is that true? Does $V$ need to be connected? It seems not.

The idea is that since $C(V)$ is a union of lines passing through the origin, it should be possible to simultaneously contract each of these lines down to a single point ($0$, the origin). I'm thinking that there is a deformation retraction of $C(V)$ onto $0$
$$C(V)\times [0,1] \rightarrow C(V)$$
given by
$$(v,t)\rightarrow (1-t)v.$$

Is this correct?

Comment: Are you using the Euclidean topology rather than the Zariski topology? If so, this is a duplicate of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/344106/does-star-convex-imply-contractibility), as the cone is star-convex with respect to the cone point as you point out.

Comment: Yes, using the Euclidean topology. Thanks for the reference! My question is not *quite* a duplicate though, right? Even though it is apparently quite easy to see that the affine cone is a star domain and hence contractible by the linked question.

Comment: Happy to point out the reference. And it depends what you mean by duplicate - I meant "essentially answered by the linked question".

Comment: I understand. Thanks again.